# Accessing form-data with multer in Express js/Node

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, middleware, multer

i have a route in which i have a simple middleware after which i have a multer middleware and after that i have my final function. i cant seem to figure out how would i access my form data from the front end in the first middleware. i can access them in the final function which is after the multer middleware, but not in the first middleware. im sending id from the frontend and in my route's final function i can access the id as req.body.id. however i cannot access it in my first middleware. below is my route

```
route.post('/upload', [checkSize, upload.single('file')], file_controller.upload)
```

below is my checkSize middleware

```
var db = require('../database/connection');

checkSize = async (req, res, next) => {

let dbo = await db();

let initSize = await dbo.stats();

if(1 === 1){

    return res.send("middleware is working" + " " + req.body.id);

}else{

    req.initSize = initSize.dataSize/1000000
    next()
}
}
    module.exports = checkSize
```

the Result in the response comes out to be

"middleware is working *undefined*"

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the order of middleware.

```
route.post('/upload', [upload.single('file'), checkSize], file_controller.upload)
```

Second of all the file is available at `req.file` not `req.body` field. `req.body` field will contain all the text fields of a form.

Comment: No actually i need my checkSize middle ware before the upload as i need to upload based on some condition. And that condition is in checkSize. And i need req.body in the checkSize middleware as my condition needs a text field from the form-data. Im sending both the file and textfield(id) from my form

Comment: Well, the `multer` handles the form data so you can not access it until `multer` processed the form-data so you need to change the order, then you can reject the request anyway if it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: that wont work for me. im using multer gridfs storage, i need to check another mongodb collection before uploading my file and to check that collection i need an id which i am sending from my form-data. so i need to access that id in the checkSize middleware

Comment: The solution is to change the logic a little, `multer` should upload the file into `reques.file` field and then you should add custom logic afterward to upload it to MongoDB GridFS, so that you could perform validation after you get the file and the form data, and if everything is okay upload it to the MongoDB GridFS. Does this help?

Comment: No. theres to way to stop image from uploading once the gridfs storage file function runs. the only option left is to create another api to check for the condition and handle it from the frontend. Internet and nodeJs really failed me here